# nunit tests do not complete when testing async mvc5 controller (vs 2015)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, async-await, nunit-3.0, resharper-10.0

I have an mvc 5 controller that makes use of some async data access code. I've written a simple test using nUnit.  The test doesn't complete, it just spins until i cancel it.  afaik i've set up the test correctly; it's awaiting the controller action is marked as async and returns a task.  Am i missing something?  Interestingly, the test works when i mock out the dependencies using moq, but if i go for an integration test with the actual dependencies in place, it just spins forever.

the a simplified test:

```
[Test]
    public async Task Get_WhenProductHasData_ReturnsView()
    {
        // Arrange
        ...

        // Act
        PartialViewResult actualResult = await _controller.Widget(_productId1) as PartialViewResult;


        // Assert
        Assert.That(actualResult, Is.Not.Null);
...
    }
```

And here's the simplified controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Widget(string productId)
    {

        ProductStats stats = await _statsService.GetProductStatsAsync(productId);


        return PartialView(stats);
    }
```

Comment: You have to specify that you want the awaited task to return as a PartialViewResult, not the task itself, notice the added parenthesis. `PartialViewResult actualResult = (await _controller.Widget(_productId1)) as PartialViewResult;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Igor. That didn't work though.  Still just spins...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
[Test]
public async Task Get_WhenProductHasData_ReturnsView()
{
    // Arrange
    ...

    // Act
    var result = await _controller.Widget(_productId1);


    // Assert
    Assert.That(result as PartialViewResult, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

Note that the "Act" line is simply `awaiting` and the result is then cast as a `PartialViewResult` on the `Assert.That` line, if it was `null` or not a `PartialViewResult` type it would return `null`. Either way you get what you're looking for.